# To get a menu for a code-beautifier in Vim by a mouse click

Tags: vim

I have never used a mouse click to get a hovering menu in Vim.
The [following manual](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simple_code_beautifier) suggests such a menu exists.

> Here are a few vimrc lines that can
>   help. Put them in your vimrc - -, then
>   you can beautify at least single lines
>   using one mouse click.

```
nmenu Misc.Beautify.For :s/for\s*(\s*/for ( /<CR>:s/\s*)\s*$/ )/<CR>:s/\(\i\+\)\s*=\s*/\1 = /<CR>:s/\s*\([=<>!]=\\|[<>]\)\s*/ \1 /<CR>:s/\s*\(--\\|++\)/\1/<CR>:s/\s*;\s*/; /g<CR>
nmenu Misc.Beautify.Func :s/\s*)/ )/g<CR>:s/\s*\([(,]\)\s*/\1 /g<CR>:s/(\s\+)/()/g<CR>
nmenu Misc.Beautify.If :s/if\s*(\s*/if ( /<CR>:s/\s*)\s*$/ )/<CR>:silent s/\s*\([=<>!]=\\|[<>]\)\s*/ \1 /<CR>
nmenu Misc.Beautify.Assign :s/\s*\([-+*\/&\|]\?\)\s*=\s*/ \1= /g<CR>
```

I found onlythe following lines about nmenu in Vim docs. They are not really useful.

```
   :nmenu Words.Add\ Var         wb"zye:menu! Words.<C-R>z <C-R>z<CR>
   :nmenu Words.Remove\ Var      wb"zye:unmenu! Words.<C-R>z<CR>
```

It seems that my Vim 7.2 does not have such a hovering menu.
The manual suggests to remove the `nmenu` to get a code-beautifier for many lines. This suggests me that I have misunderstood the action button for the beautifier. It is not apparently only a mouse click.

**How can you use the code beautifier in Vim?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`:h creating-menus`](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/gui.html#creating-menus): `:menu` creates new entries on the menu bar, which only exists in gVim.

If you do not see a menu bar in your gVim, see [`:h 'go'`](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/options.html#'guioptions'): you may need to `:set guioptions+=m`.  The menu bar is above the toolbar, if any, which is above the editing area.

```
:nmenu Misc.Beautify.For :s/for\s*(\s*/for ( /:s/\s*)\s*$/ )/:s/\(\i\+\)\s*=\s*/\1 = /:s/\s*\([=!]=\\|[]\)\s*/ \1 /:s/\s*\(--\\|++\)/\1/:s/\s*;\s*/; /g
:nmenu Misc.Beautify.Func :s/\s*)/ )/g:s/\s*\([(,]\)\s*/\1 /g:s/(\s\+)/()/g
:nmenu Misc.Beautify.If :s/if\s*(\s*/if ( /:s/\s*)\s*$/ )/:silent s/\s*\([=!]=\\|[]\)\s*/ \1 /
:nmenu Misc.Beautify.Assign :s/\s*\([-+*\/&\|]\?\)\s*=\s*/ \1= /g
```

Outside of gVim, this does nothing.  Within gVim, as long as the menu bar is enabled, you will have a Misc menu with a Beautify submenu.  For convenience, you may "tear" the menu off  (`:set go+=t` and click the snipper at the top of the menu) into a floating menu bar of its own, giving you one-click access to the items in the submenu.

Comment: *Is there any way to get the functionality to Vim?* --- I am not sure whether key mappings are possible here or not.

Comment: I run the following mapping unsuccessfully `map <C-w>1 Misc...` It pastes the actual sed-codes to my editing codes. The problem seems to be that the insertion of code to `:` -mode. **How can you paste the code to `:` -mode such that the formatting happens?**

Comment: Which `:map` command are you using?  If it starts in insert mode, you will of course need to exit to normal mode before commands can work; `<C-\><C-N>` will go to normal mode (without causing a beep like `<Esc>` does if you're already in normal mode).